# why are styles not getting applied to Django URLField

Tags: django

I have a model for the profile in it there are different fields like CharField and also URLField but on the page, the styles are getting applied to the input of other fields but are not getting applied to the input of URLField

here is my models.py:

[image]

and here is my forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        "name",
        "email",
        "username",
        "location",
        "bio",
        "short_intro",
        "profile_image",
        "social_github",
        "social_twitter",
        "social_linkedin",
        "social_youtube",
        "social_website",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({"class": "input"})
```

and here is my HTML:

```html
{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}



<!-- Main Section -->
<main class="formPage my-xl">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="formWrapper">
            <a class="backButton" href="{% url 'account' %}"><i class="im im-angle-left"></i></a>
            <br>

            <form action="{% url 'edit-account' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form__field">
                    <label for="formInput#text">{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg  my-md" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is an example of gif of what's happening:
[image]

**Please answer how can I apply the same styles on the input of URLField as well**

Comment: Inspect your HTML code and see if there is a class="input"  in your URL fields. If not - make sure those fields are being iterated in `for name, field in self.fields.items():` (just pring name and field). If yes - make sure your CSS rules are valid for url fields.

Comment: @AlexParamonov the fields are being iterated but how do I check that the CSS rules are valid for URL fields or not

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to see that CSS styles are applied. Usually yo do inspect element and to the right there is a column with CSS styles applied. Check that css rules are there for url fields and also check CSS definition for "input" class, it may have a limitation to which fields t applied in its declaration.